# OpenCV image correction to fill blank spaces and holes in image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently working on a project with floorplan images. I'm dealing with a problem where I have a certain output, but often times it's in a need of a bit correction. This is what i have:

The upper image is the predicted output and the bottom one is the ground truth. What would be the optimal way for example to correct the spots missing the black fillings?

[image]

Comment: maybe [Morphological Transformations] (https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-transformations) can help you

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have round corners on some of your ground truth?

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use morphological transformations with a clever trick. If you just use normal morph closing to fill the holes, it will not work due to the curved ends of the walls. So to get around this, we can isolate the walls into two parts by first detecting all horizontal walls and then vertical walls one at a time. Once we have isolated each orientation, we find the rectangular contour which will effectively create the corner point of the wall. Here's a visualization:

Input image

[image]

Detected horizontal and vertical walls drawn in by a rectangle fill

[image]
[image]

Combined masks

[image]

Color mask on input image to get result

[image]

Here's the results with the 2nd input image

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, create mask, grayscale, and Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('2.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Perform morph operations
open_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, open_kernel, iterations=1)
close_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, close_kernel, iterations=3)

# Find horizontal sections and draw rectangle on mask 
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,3))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,255,255), -1)
    cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,255,255), 2)

# Find vertical sections and draw rectangle on mask 
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,25))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,255,255), -1)
    cv2.rectangle(mask, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255,255,255), 2)

# Color mask onto original image
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image[mask==255] = [0,0,0]

cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('close', close)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```